# Lookup in LINQ to be based only on 1 column from joined collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Scrape collection with one of the columns being MPN code. I want to find a matching MPN code in one of few columns in Aws collection - however in Aws MPN can be found in MPN column, but it can alternatively appear in Model, ItemPartNumber etc. columns. Sometimes MPN is repeated in the same row in more than 1 column in Aws.

If I find the row with matching MPN in any columns, I want to stop searching this row and just take corresponding EAN from Aws. So ultimately the amount of rows in Scrape should not change after the query.

However with this query I get more rows, which looks like it finds matches on MPN then separately on ItemPartNumber, Model etc. and cumulates them.

How would I reformulate the query so I get Scrape with same amount of rows at at the start, enhanced with a EAN code from Aws?

```
public IEnumerable<Scrape> EnhanceWith(IEnumerable<Aws> awsData)
{
    IEnumerable<Scrape> query = from scr in scrapeData
                                from aws in awsData
                                where
                                (
                                    scr.MPN == aws.ItemPartNumber ||
                                    scr.MPN == aws.Model ||
                                    scr.MPN == aws.MPN ||
                                    scr.MPN == aws.PartNumber 
                                )
                                select
                                new Scrape
                                {
                                    EAN = aws.EAN,
                                    MPN = scr.MPN,
                                    Url = scr.Url,
                                };
    return query;
}
```

Comment: What should happen if there is not a match?

Comment: Is there any order of preference in the `aws` columns? I mean, if two records have a matching `MPN`, one in `ItemPartNumber`, one in `Model`, should the record with the matching `ItemPartNumber` take precedence over `Model`?

Comment: @Gert There should be no preference, as they will be exactly the same if they are matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join the collections, you can do a look up:

```
IEnumerable<Scrape> query = scrapeData.Select(scr => 
{
    scr.EAN= awsData.FirstOrDefault(aws => scr.MPN == aws.ItemPartNumber ||
                                           scr.MPN == aws.Model ||
                                           scr.MPN == aws.MPN ||
                                           scr.MPN == aws.PartNumber)?.EAN;
    return scr;
});
return query;
```

Comment: Please note that in general, it is not recommended that queries modify existing data. Instead, they should create new instances of data and leave the original data untouched.

Comment: I agree. I personally wouldn't do this with a query, but with a `ForEach`-iterator. If you still want to use a query, this will have a (marginally) better performance as you don't have to allocate that many objects. Performance vs best practice, etc...

Comment: Thank you Kenneth, I'm checking this.

Comment: Thank you gents for this good exchange of thoughts, this helps me as well to understand this better.

Comment: @Kenneth - how do you apply the return scr in the 7th line? It's like a method within linq query?? I have never seen this. Could you recommend some reading on this topic?

Comment: When you do a select inside a LINQ-query, it asks for a `Func<TSource, TResult>` . In this case `TSource` and `TResult` are the same : `Scrape`. `TSource` is the type of the `IEnumerable`you're querying (`scrapeData`) and the type of the item you get passed (`scr`). `TResult` is the type you return from this function (here `scr` again). A `Func` can be created in two ways: either with an expression: `item => result` where the `return` keyword is implied or as above with `{ }` around it, and then you can just write any method you want

Comment: Thank you Kenneth, I ultimately went to an easier solution at this stage which you suggested - foreach loop. But this works, and thank you for your explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result =
    scrapeData
    .Select(scr => 
        new
        {
            SCR = scr,
            AWS = 
                awsData
                .FirstOrDefault(aws =>
                    scr.MPN == aws.ItemPartNumber ||
                    scr.MPN == aws.Model ||
                    scr.MPN == aws.MPN ||
                    scr.MPN == aws.PartNumber)
        })
    .Where(x => x.AWS != null)
    .Select(x => new Scrape
    {
        EAN = x.AWS.EAN,
        MPN = x.SCR.MPN,
        Url = x.SCR.Url,
    });
```

For each Scrape in `scrapeData`, we search for the first match in the `awsData` and we put the result in an anonymous object. Then we filter out the items where the matched Aws is `null` to remove the cases were a match was not found, and then for each item we create a new `Scrape` object with the required information from both the original `Scrape` object and the found `Aws` object.

If you want to include the cases where a match is not found, then simply remove the `Where` method call and check for `null` when you create the new `Scrape` objects like this:

```
    //.Where(x => x.AWS != null)
    .Select(x => new Scrape
    {
        EAN = x.AWS != null ? x.AWS.EAN : x.SCR.EAN,
        MPN = x.SCR.MPN,
        Url = x.SCR.Url,
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Yacoub, I need to digest it.